# Mac option symbols not appearing in pdf

Tags: symbols, mac

Simply put, Apple option symbols such as § are not appearing in the pdf file when I build it. Other symbols (e.g., shift symbols) appear. There is no problem building the pdf either.

To be incredibly unhelpful, I have no idea when option symbols stopped showing up, but they were definitely working at some time prior. Since the pdf is getting built without issue, I don't know where to start looking.

I'm hoping someone can tell me what should I be looking for to remedy this problem, or failing that, if there is an easy workaround.

Below I have included the relevant code in which I keep all of my packages etc.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report} 


\title{A PhD Thesis}
\author{Some Bloke}
\date{2019}

% PACKAGE FOR GRAPHS (chapter 7)

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees}

\tikzset{
  basic/.style  = {draw, text width=2cm, font=\sffamily, rectangle},
  root/.style   = {basic, rounded corners=2pt, thin, align=center,
                   },
  level 2/.style = {basic, rounded corners=6pt, thin,align=center, ,
                   text width=8em},
  level 3/.style = {basic, thin, align=left, , text width=6.5em}
}

% PACKAGE FOR TITLES -----------

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}


%PACKAGES -------------

\usepackage[phd]{edmaths}
\linespread{1.25}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage[super]{nth}

\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

%END PACKAGES ---------

\newcommand{\ndd}{Unpublished}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\UseRawInputEncoding

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

Crikey! What big ∞∞ you have grandma!
Blimey! What big ••• you have grandma!
Streuth! What big §§§ you have grandma!

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{PhD_refs}

\end{document}
```

As you can see, it's an utter mess and, again, since the pdf is being built without interruption, I don't know when precisely this became a problem.

Comment: Show a small, complete example of your code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: ... and welcome to TeX.SE by the way.  [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: What encoding are you using for that file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've edited the initial post to include (what I hope is) the relevant code.

Comment: @HerbSchulz I've edited the initial post to include (what I hope is) the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `\UseRawInputEncoding`. Then give the ∞ a declaration. Then it should compile (assuming a current tex system + latex)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{221E}{\ensuremath{\infty}}
\begin{document}

Crikey! What big ∞∞ you have grandma!
Blimey! What big ••• you have grandma!
Streuth! What big §§§ you have grandma!


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Okay, now I'm receiving the following error ---   

! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.
See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.1193 Machery, �.
%
The document does not appear to be in UTF-8 encoding.
Try adding \UseRawInputEncoding as the first line of the file
or specify an encoding such as \usepackage [latin1]{inputenc}
in the document preamble.
Alternatively, save the file in UTF-8 using your editor or another tool

----
Any ideas on this?

Comment: Convert your document to utf8. That is the standard encoding nowadays. Make a backup first, in case you mess it up.